# A book I read as a teen: maze that transports you to the past, girl chasing baby carriage

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read this book 21 years ago. The main points I remember from the book are a maze that transports you to the past: in the present the maze is chalk I think, and in the past it's a full hedge maze. Also there was a baby carriage that travels being chased by a girl, and an old woman who offered candy but the candy was all melted together. There are a couple of other books I can't remember but I'll only do one at a time.

Comment: Can you remember any more details? Was it written in English? Novel or short story? When did you read it (i.e. when were you a teen)? What did the cover look like? How did it end?

Comment: It was a full book I believe... But this was 21 years ago... The only other thing I can remember is in the present the maze is chalk I think and in the past its a full hedge maze... Sorry for lack of detail

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the movie Labyrinth?

Comment: @StephenJohnson Excellent, thanks! The chalk/hedge detail was enough for me to find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like the 1989 novel [*Mazemaker*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2407582.Mazemaker) by Catherine Dexter.

Someone else has asked a similar question [here](http://www.whatsthatbook.com/?xq=506), which is how I found the book. Quoting from the reviews [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0688073832) (emphasis mine):

> Winnie and her friend Harry have only the city schoolyard to hang out in, with its broken glass and graffiti-covered walls. But one day a cat they've found runs through a spray-painted maze they discover--and disappears. Winnie, too, **runs the maze, which transports her through time to 1889**, and delivers her into the hands of a deranged woman, Mrs. Minot, who is determined to use the maze's power for herself. Winnie learns of others who have disappeared; if she is to find her own way home, she must prevent Mrs. Minot from altering time. While not as chilling as Dexter's Oracle Doll , Mazemaker is still riveting, with likable characters in Winnie, Harry and Lily. The ending, if plausible, is a little too easy, but overall the book is a worthwhile read. **Ages 10-14.**
>
> When Winnie finds a large, intricate **maze spray-painted on a deserted playground**, she can't resist trying to negotiate it. As she triumphantly reaches the center, she finds herself transported 100 years into the past, but on the same spot--in the center of an overgrown but still discernible **hedge maze**.